# Socket Programming For Audio Streaming using Bluetooth or wifi

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, streaming

I know that for audio streaming and video streaming RTSP protocol is used (However i am not aware of what is used in bluetooth).

However my question is little different.I would like to explain it with an example(Actually it is not an example i am trying to build something similar).

When we connect our device(a mobile running on android) using bluetooth to our PC(Operating System-Windows) the 
control panel shows an option for streaming audio.
As many of you would be aware in this when i play a song on my device it is played on my PC speakers.

So my question is
 
1)Who is the server
2)Who is the client

Probably i think that my PC is the client.If PC is the client then it would open a connection for audio streaming with the device.
As it opens a connection with the server, the server should have a specific application through which the transfer of packets must take place with the client.

But to my surprise i was able to use any media player on my device to play songs on my laptop speaker.

How is this possible?? Is it possible to do the same thing using RTSP protocol.